# How to search a specific word in child line. if match is found return parent and child line

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

In below data find "10.10.10.1" if match is found return its parent line that is "ip access-list extended test2" and matching line " permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log"

input :
data_list=

```
ip access-list extended test2 10.10.10.1
ip access-list extended test1
 deny   tcp any eq tacacs any
 permit ip any any
ip access-list extended test2
 permit ip any any
 permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log
 permit icmp host 10.10.10.1 any
 permit tcp any any eq 22
 permit tcp any any eq tacacs
 permit tcp any any
 permit udp any any
ip access-list extended test3
 permit udp any any eq 123 log
 permit udp any any eq 1234 log
 permit ip any any
```

The output should be:

```
ip access-list extended test2
 permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log
```

this what I tried but I able to return only matching line I do not know how to match parent line

```
final_list = []
    for LINE in data_list:
    if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format('10.10.10.1'), LINE):
        final_list.append(LINE)
    print(final_list)
```

Comment: How can the parent be identified? with the indentation?

Comment: Could you also add the code/snippets you have tried so far and also what problems you are facing if any?

Comment: it has to identify whichever line above child line has no space or tab at the starting of the line.

Comment: I added what I tried so far but it return only the matching line. I do not know how to bring its parent line above child line.

Comment: Parent line can be identified if there is no space at the beginning of the line. if there is space at the beginning  those all are child lines of parent line

Answer (score 1):

I have stored device configuration in device_config.cfg file. using ciscoconfparse and regex module I am able to do this.

```
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
import re


final_list = []
cisco_file = 'device_config.cfg'

cisco_cfg = CiscoConfParse(cisco_file)
parent_child_line = cisco_cfg.find_objects_w_child(parentspec=r"", childspec=r"10.10.10.10")
parsed_data = cisco_cfg.find_objects(r"10.10.10.10")

# print(parent_child_line)
# print(parsed_data)

for p_line in parent_child_line:
    # print(p_line.text)
    final_list.append(p_line.text)
    for child in p_line.children:
        if re.search(r'10.10.10.10', child.text):
            # print(child.text)
            final_list.append(child.text)

print('\n#############################################\n')

for i in parsed_data:
    if not re.search(r'^\s\w', i.text):
        # print(i.text)
        final_list.append(i.text)
        print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
reg = r' .*10\.10\.10\.1.*'
data = """
ip access-list extended test1
 deny   tcp any eq tacacs any
 permit ip any any
ip access-list extended test2
 permit ip any any
 permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log
 permit icmp host 10.10.10.2 any
 permit tcp any any eq 22
 permit tcp any any eq tacacs
 permit tcp any any
 permit udp any any
ip access-list extended test3
 permit udp any any eq 123 log
 permit udp any any eq 1234 log
 permit ip any any
""" #read your data your way (open(file) or args)
dataLines = data.split('\n')
while '' in dataLines:
    dataLines.remove('')
print(dataLines)
parent = ''

for i in dataLines:
    if not i[0] == ' ':
        parent = i
        continue
    else:
        if re.match(reg, i):
            print('\n'+parent)
            print(i)
            break
```

This might help...

Comment: * This assumes your parent line doesn't start with a space and you child line always start with a space...

Comment: yes.. this is working for me.. thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, we can do it without regex assuming that by `parent line` you mean the line starting with `ip access-list`.

```py
parent_line = None

# data being the input string
for line in data.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('ip access-list'):
        parent_line = line
    elif '10.10.10.1' in line:
        print(parent_line)
        print(line)
```

It prints:

```py
ip access-list extended test2
permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log
```

---

This code will need very minor changes if the parent and child lines need to be identified based on whitespace at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest re-grouping `data_list` strings into separate, individual lists  and then check for a match and grab the results once the conditions are met.

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/rp5ILd):

```py
import re
data = """ip access-list extended test1
 deny   tcp any eq tacacs any
 permit ip any any
ip access-list extended test2
 permit ip any any
 permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log
 permit icmp host 10.10.10.2 any
 permit tcp any any eq 22
 permit tcp any any eq tacacs
 permit tcp any any
 permit udp any any
ip access-list extended test3
 permit udp any any eq 123 log
 permit udp any any eq 1234 log
 permit ip any any"""

data_list = data.splitlines()
data_ll = []
search_key = '10.10.10.1'
tmp = []
for line in data_list:
    if line and not line[0].isspace():
        if tmp:
            m = re.search(fr".*\b{re.escape(search_key)}\b.*", "\n".join(tmp))
            if m:
                data_ll.append([tmp[0], m.group()])
            tmp = [line.rstrip()]
        else:
            tmp.append(line.rstrip())
    elif line and line[0].isspace():
        tmp.append(line.rstrip())

print(data_ll)
```

Output:

```
[['ip access-list extended test2', ' permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log']]
```

I also initialize the regex from the `search_key` variable and that is why I use the `re.escape(search_key)` to escape the `.` chars, else, they match any chars other than line feeds.

Comment: this is working good but its not returning more than one child line matching in a group.

Comment: @razz And what do you expect to get?

Comment: I am expecting all matching child lines below parent line but here I am getting only one child line per parent line though it has more than one matching child line. Also If a parent line has matching key_word but it does have child line in the output its duplicating parent line as child line but in this case I am expecting only matching parent line since it doesn't have child line

example output:
```
[['ip access-list extended test2 10.10.10.1'], ['ip access-list extended test2', ' permit ip host 10.10.10.1 any log', ' permit icmp host 10.10.10.1 any']]
```

Comment: @razz I can't get what you mean. [Here](https://ideone.com/Ntb6uD), you get the whole block in a list as a return value.

Comment: I figured it out using the other way for cisco config.. adding my solution in below